# TestDFSIO hdfs on exiting files

Tags: hadoop, jar, hdfs, benchmarking

Hello Im implementing a new technique in hdfs to enhance storage, throughput and access time.
I need to measure the read/write performance on my existing files on HDFS, I found this benchmark TestDFSIO.

```
hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-3.2.1-tests.jar TestDFSIO -read -nrFiles 100 -fileSize 80MB -resFile /TestDFSIOwrite.txt
```

How to specify this jar to be executed on my exiting files on HDFS

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at DFSIO [source code](https://github.com/c9n/hadoop/blob/a315107901aebc8d0c2b9f530d191673d27922a2/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java#L110), you can see configuration is being loaded from multiple files into `config` variable.

```
  private Configuration config;

  static{
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("hdfs-default.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("hdfs-site.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("mapred-default.xml");
    Configuration.addDefaultResource("mapred-site.xml");
  }
```

And its getting read directory [here, in `getReadDir` method](https://github.com/c9n/hadoop/blob/a315107901aebc8d0c2b9f530d191673d27922a2/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/src/test/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TestDFSIO.java#L186).

```
  private static Path getReadDir(Configuration conf) {
    return new Path(getBaseDir(conf), "io_read");
  }
```

so you might try adding `io_read` config into `mapred-site.xml` to see what happens.